# Getting the bits of an int into a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am building a lightweight high-precision arithmetic library for one of my Java applications and have been doing quite a bit of bit-twiddling (pun intended). Occasionally I get an `int` that has to be be converted into a `long` via simple word extension i.e. the 32 least significant bits of the `long` should become equal to the bits of the `int`.

Unfortunately, casting only works correctly for positive numbers. In addition, using an `int` in the same arithmetic expression with a `long` will implicitly cast to `long` beforehand, which means that e.g. this will not work if `i` is negative:

```
long l = (i & 0xffffffffL);
```

Currently I am using something along the lines of:

```
long l = (((long)(i >>> 8)) << 8) | (i & 0xff);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I may be missing something:

```
int i = -1;

long l = (i | 0xffffffffL);

System.out.println(l);
```

This prints out `-1` rather than `4294967295`. *What* am I missing?

**EDIT 2:**

Ooops... `|` instead of `&`. How the **** did the little ****** get there?

**EDIT 3:**

I have *no* idea how exactly I missed it, but this works perfectly:

```
long l = (i & 0xffffffffL);
```

...which makes this question completely irrelevant, I guess.

Comment: Your first code should work fine - I've just tried it, and for example if `i` is -1, `l` becomes 4294967295. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @JonSkeet: You tried it and it works? It does not seem to work for me - see my edit...

Comment: Your edit uses `|` instead of `&`...

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think I urgently need a few hours of uninterrupted sleep. Or maybe I need to stop doing bitwise stuff for a few days and do some light coding to clear my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually test the `long l = (i & 0xffffffffL);` code? Yes, the value of `i` will be converted to long first, which means either 0-extension if `i` is positive or 1-extension if `i` is negative. In either case the lower 32 bits are not affected, so unless I misunderstand the problem, the `&` operation should leave you with the result you want.

Comment: I did test *twice*. The first attempt was part of a larger codebase where another bug messed things up. The second self-contained test had a typo. Sigh... I need a vacation... somewhere warm... with lots of scantily-clad ladies...

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `long l = (i | 0xffffffffL);` in your second example.

It should be:

```
long l = (i & 0xffffffffL);
```

and then you will get the result you are expecting.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that too, albeit a bit (!) late. It's a wonder how sometimes you find the answer just after posting to SO, even if there is no actual answer...